# TYPO3 : clear big mysql tables

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.2.x

On my TYPO3 6.2 website some SQL tables became quite big :

- tx_realurl_urlcache **557Mo**
- cf_cache_hash **15.5Mo**
- tx_kesearch_stat_search **15.4Mo**
- tx_kesearch_stat_word **19.6Mo**
- sys_refindex **18.1Mo**

Please notice that all the others tables (about 100 tables) are all combined > 15Mo ... so my question is simple :

-> Which one could I delete ? Is it safe or not ?
I have bad experiences in the past with TYPO3 database cleanup then I rather ask you for advice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TLDR: the only tables which could be cleared are cache tables, but they cost you performance and will build up again soon.

you might clear these tables and these propably will build up again, but you will suffer.

- tx_realurl_urlcache - here realurl stores the generated urls, if you truncate it the url decoding might break/ some urls might be unknown = your page breaks
- cf_cache_* - can be truncated but will be rebuild, meanwhile your server needs to rebuild the information. it is slower.
- tx_kesearch_stat_search / tx_kesearch_stat_word - these two belong to the kesearch-extension and include the index information of your page. Truncating will terminate the search until the tables are rebuild
- sys_refindex - here TYPO3 stores the references which will help you to avoid deleting used files or records. (normaly this index is rebuild with a scheduler task to get consistent data)

Comment: Hi @Bernd Wilke πφ, thank you  for all the details. I'm going to be careful and make no operations at all on thoses tables ;)

Answer (score 2):

Do not delete the table! You can truncate some tables.

If you want to clean up some cache just flush all Typo3 caches in backend or just use the 'clear all cache' button inside the typo3-install tool.

Comment: Hi @Evo sorry for this mistake, obviously I meant truncate, not delete. I already use "clear all caches" button but I wondered if thoses table sizes were normal. Thank you for your advice.

Comment: ok, maybe the [list](http://p.cweiske.de/259) can help you the next time =)